# Genymotion Nexus 10 Layout Not Recognized

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two layouts for an Activity, phone and tablet. The phone layout works fine.

I created a nexus 10 tablet layout.xml file by going to my project folder-->res-->new-->android resource directory. Here I created a directory called layout-xlarge-xhdpi and made it a layout resource type. Every time I launch my tablet in genymotion however, it keeps bringing up the phone layout.

I also tried creating an additional layout for this Activity for the tablet, which is sw600dp size and still nothing. Does anybody know why? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sw720dp-xxhdpi is the correct layout folder for nexus 10.For testing purpose

> 1- create all available layout folder
>   2- test with an xml layout that contains the density name.

```
layout-nodpi/
layout-sw600dp-hdpi/
layout-sw600dp-mdpi/
layout-sw600dp-xhdpi/
layout-sw600dp-xxhdpi/
layout-sw600dp-xxxhdpi/
layout-sw720dp-hdpi/
layout-sw720dp-mdpi/
layout-sw720dp-xhdpi/
layout-sw720dp-xxhdpi/
layout-sw720dp-xxxhdpi/
```

Comment: My layout is called activity_main_login. I click on create new resource layout file, name it activity_main_login, under available qualifiers  I highlight "smallest screen width" and set it to 720. It creates a file for me called activity_main_login.xml(sw720dp). The tablet is still not recognizing this. I also created one called activity_main_login.xml(sw720dp-xxhdpi) and still nothing.

Comment: I actually tested again and sw720dp-xxhdpi is the right folder for nexus 10 , unless other misconfigurations. So to be sure that everthing is ok i suggest creating all tablet folder.see my edited answer.